# Getting 404 error when connecting angular proxy config with spring mvc

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-proxy

Am trying to connect angular with spring mvc using proxy json.
i have tried multiple attempts, but always throwing 404 error.

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/employees 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the snippet of my code block.
Thanks in advance.

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/api/v1": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
getAllEmployees() {
    this._http.get('/api/v1/employees').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.result = data.toString();
      },
      error => {
      });
}
```

**controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/employees")
    public String getDisplayMessage() {
        return "Hi Welcome!!!";
    }   
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Assume getAllEmployee() method called when clicking html button.

I can get message "Hi Welcome!!!" , when i try **http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/api/v1/employees**

Can someone tell me where did i coded wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the inconsistency: your code does a request to `/api/v1/employees` witch is proxied to (we just prepend `http://localhost:8080`) `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees` and in your api as you said path `http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/api/v1/employees` is expected. I believe your proxy should be

```
{
    "/api/v1": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution and its worked well !!!.
Thank you